# How to get label's id?

Tags: javascript

This is index.html

```
<html>
  <head>
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="add.js"></script>
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="get.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="list">
      <form id="programs" name="programs">
      </form>
      <input type="button" value="add" onClick="add();" />
      <input type="button" value="delete" onClick="get();" />
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is add.js

```
var program_number = 0;

function add()
{
  var program_name = "program_sample";

  var formID = document.getElementById("programs");
  var labelTag = document.createElement("label");
  var inputTag = document.createElement("input");

  var txtNode = document.createTextNode("program " + program_number);
  var brTag = document.createElement("br");

  // set input attribute
  inputTag.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");
  inputTag.setAttribute("name", program_name);
  inputTag.setAttribute("value", "program" + program_number);

  // set label attribute
  labelTag.setAttribute("id", "program_label" + program_number);

  labelTag.appendChild(inputTag);
  labelTag.appendChild(txtNode);
  labelTag.appendChild(brTag);

  formID.appendChild(labelTag);

  program_number++;
}
```

This is get.js

```
function get()
{
  var programs = document.programs;

  for(var i = 0; i < programs.length; i++)
    console.log(programs[i].id);
}
```

Hello, I want to get the label's id dynamically. add.js code makes it. (below)

```
<label id="program_label0>
    <input type="checkbox" name="program_sample" value="program0" />
    program 0<\br>
</label>
```

If those run normally, the result can be "program_label1", "program_label2", "program_label3" ...

but the result of get.js is just a blank. What should I do to get label's id ..?
or Where my code is wrong ..?

Comment: What's this funny font?

Comment: He means don't use italics to make your code etc. "stand out"

Comment: You're looping through forms, not labels within the form. This should do it: `var programs = document.programs.getElementsByTagName('label');` http://jsfiddle.net/MelanciaUK/gf2Lkrcs/

Answer (score 1):

Inside your 'get.js' you could try either

```
var programs = document.getElementById("programs");
```

or

```
var programs = document.forms["programs"];
```

or

```
var programs = document.forms[0];
```

The last one will work only if the form you are referring to is only presented first inside DOM tree.

Answer (score 1):

I see a few problems:

1. Inputs in the beginning html are outside the form...(Please refer to [w3schools form basics](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp))
2. Instead of **inputTag.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");**, you should use **inputTage.type = "checkbox"**;
3. There is no such thing as **documents.programs**. To access your programs DOM element, please do as in your add.js and **document.getElementById("programs")**;
4. You do not seem clear on how basics work. - **var formID = document.getElementById("programs");** will not return a formID... will return a DOM element. Please read more basic tutorials. Start at - [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/)

Comment: @MelanciaUK: Have you visited that link lately?

Comment: Which one? The Schools or the Fools?

Comment: Not really. Actually, none of them.

Comment: @MelanciaUK: The w3fools site doesn't have the scathing critique that it used to. I just noticed this the other day.

Comment: My comment shouldn't even be here, but I thought it would be OK. A bit of joy in a Saturday night (UK). :)

Answer (score 0):

First: Why are you using setAttribute over setting the properties?

Second:

```
var programs = document.getElementById("programs");
```

More than likely you mean to access `window.programs` in your code, which only works had that element been in the document when you loaded the page.

When you create an element and add it to the DOM, it does not update the global object (here called `window`), with that new property name.

Answer (score 0):

You should access form element with `document.programs.elements[i]. So you have missed "elements" which is collection of form elements.

Comment: what's document.programs exactly?

Comment: It is his form with access by name.